# How to configure UFW Ubuntu server for Kamailio SIP Server?

Tags: security, iptables, ufw, sip

I need to configure UFW or iptables to secure Kamailio on my ubuntu server.
I followed this [kamailio-security](https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/tutorials/security/kamailio-security) but I don't know how to configure it.

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:CHECK_TCP - [0:0]
:ICMP - [0:0]
:PRIVATE - [0:0]
:PSD - [0:0]
:SERVICES - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p ipv6 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j SERVICES 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -m state --state INVALID,NEW,RELATED -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-option 64 -j DROP 
-A CHECK_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-option 128 -j DROP 
-A ICMP -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11/1 -m limit --limit 5/sec -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A ICMP -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11/0 -m limit --limit 5/sec -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A ICMP -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -m limit --limit 10/sec -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A ICMP -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 10/sec --limit-burst 10 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A ICMP -p icmp -j DROP 
-A PRIVATE -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP 
-A PRIVATE -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP 
-A PRIVATE -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP 
-A PRIVATE -j RETURN 
-A PSD -p tcp -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.050000 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A PSD -p tcp -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.050000 -j TARPIT  --reset 
-A PSD -p tcp -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.500000 -j TARPIT  --tarpit 
-A PSD -p udp -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.050000 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A PSD -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.050000 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable  
-A SERVICES -p icmp -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A SERVICES -p icmp -j ICMP 
-A SERVICES -p tcp -j CHECK_TCP 
-A SERVICES -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A SERVICES -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A SERVICES -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A SERVICES -p tcp -m udp -m multiport --dports 5060 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A SERVICES -p tcp -m udp -m multiport --dports 5061 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A SERVICES -i eth0 -j PSD 
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kamailio is a [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) and optional [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP) server
So you have to allow [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) and optionally [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP) protocols
The document you referring to also allows [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)
A good advice in the document suggest to use [fail2ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban), if your Kamailio server has to be exposed to the public Internet network, then  [fail2ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban) should be implemented.

```
# Allows SIP
sudo ufw allow 5060:5061/udp

# Allow RTP (optional)
sudo ufw allow 10000:20000/udp

# Allows DNS
sudo ufw allow 53/udp
sudo ufw allow 53/tcp

# Allow NTP
sudo ufw allow 123/udp
```

You can add comment to rules, specify ip adress of the server, and many more.
See the [ufw documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) and [ufw man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/ufw.8.html)